# Strange behavior with Quotename and substring

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, substring

I am seeing some behavior that I cannot figure out. We have a sproc that joins a bunch of tables and filters down some pipe-separated (|) values in a column. We cross apply a string splitter (I believe it is very much based on Jeff Moden's splitter) to separate the values. We then use the following to pull out the part we want to see based on the position of a tilde, concat some text to it and then wrap it in brackets.

`QUOTENAME( substring(tr.TableVar, 1, charindex('~', tr.TableVar) - 1) +'_someText' )`

The issue that we started to see was an error "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function." This would normally be pretty obvious to me: there's a value that does not contain a tilde. *However*, I have verified that every single record this query would return does, in fact, contain a tilde. This is both with an without any filtering done. I verified this with my eyeballs, with searching for any value that has 0 as the charindex value for the tilde, and a literal search for any record that doesn't contain a tilde (no records returned).

What makes this weirder to me is that when I remove the QUOTENAME function, there is no error. I can also take the values and place them in a temp table, run the same select on those and it produces no error.

I have also tried adding a replace to use search for a caret instead of a tilde (as below)... no error

`QUOTENAME( substring(tr.TableVar, 1, charindex('^', replace(tr.TableVar,'~','^')) - 1) +'_someText' )`

I'm kind of grasping at straws at this point. Sure, we can just use the replace method but we would also like to know *why* we're now experiencing this error (this never happened before). Is there some kind of Unicode character issue with a tilde in the QUOTENAME function? Am I even on the right track?

FWIW, we are on Azure SQL and are using collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

FYI and example (in fact the *only* value in this DB) looks like this after the split string (no quotes) 'DOG-1~3~*na*~'.

Thanks in advance for your time.

EDIT: I just went back and removed the joins to check the values without join conditions. There are indeed values that exist without the tilde. I do know that there are some cases when the engine isn't going to follow it's logical order (from, where, group by, etc) so it can effectively try to apply the substring before the filters. However, that leaves me wondering why using QUOTENAME makes that happen, and especially why using a replace doesn't throw the error; my thought would be that would cause the same issue. As always, thanks in advance

Comment: `QUOTENAME` always returns `nvarchar(258)`, which may truncate the string to a point before the character you're interested in appears.

Comment: Is that construct used in the selection criteria - the where-clause?

Comment: What you think happens is often misunderstood. The "logical" order of processing is just a model - the engine is free to process the parts of the query in any order so long as the resultset is logically consistent with the query. Often a function applied to a complex expression changes the execution plan which will hide (or illuminate) a logic flaw in the query. Here you have an assumption that your rows contain a particular character and you need to filter out those rows BEFORE the expression is evaluated or account for that situation in the expression.

Comment: Are you aware that quotename can return null when the input is larger than 128 characters?

Comment: @ErikDarling Thank you for the concise answer. This along with the gentle reminder from SMor explains it for me. Chalk it up to me to overthink (under think in this case?) a really simple problem and ask a stupid question on stack. Thanks again for the time

Comment: @SMor Thanks for the reminder. That's something I found out about when I was first learning SQL but I guess I forgot it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you suspect is indeed the problem here: **the compiler is free to evaluate expressions at any point that makes sense**, and may do so far earlier or later in the plan than you would think. This is called *"Deferred expression evaluation"*.

This can be the case even when a `Compute Scalar` operator is present at a particular position, as it is usually just a placeholder. You can tell because it normally has no `Actual Rows` values in the plan. [This has been blogged about already by @PaulWhite.](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/09/compute-scalars-expressions-and-execution-plan-performance.html)

I don't know the internals of the compiler, but I would imagine there is some heuristics to decide when to evaluate an expression. For example, it may be worth evaluating a complex expression early to avoid pushing large column values through the plan, or it may be worth deferring them to avoid evaluating them too many times.

Why did this happen only when you used `QUOTENAME`? I definitely couldn't say without seeing the plan or the query, but at a guess, for whatever reason, the compiler decided that the cost of calling `QUOTENAME` `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` early was lower than deferring them.

---

**For reference,** when calling `SUBSTRING` `LEFT` or `RIGHT` with a value taken from `CHARINDEX` or `PATINDEX`, *always always* use `NULLIF(...., 0)` to avoid these kind of problems. Since they return `0` when the search string is not found, you can null it out before it gets to `SUBSTRING`.

```
QUOTENAME(
  substring(
    tr.TableVar,
    1,
    nullif(charindex('~', tr.TableVar), 0) - 1
  ) + '_someText'
)
```